# Efficient way of reusing multiple Services having the same functionality but dealing with different entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data

I am dealing with multiple entity classes but they have the same attributes.

It's not a good data structure but according to my use case, I have to deal with two entities having the same attributes. As of now I am using multiple controllers, multiple request/response and multiple interfaces and implementations to do the logic part and save into the two corresponding tables.
Is there any efficient way that I could combine both into a single interface, with the DB operations happening in multiple DBs.

Following is a sample code:

```
@RestController
..
public class FooController  {

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @GetMapping
    public FooResponse findFoo(
            @PathVariable(FOO_CONSTANT.PATH_VARIABLE_FOO_ID) String fooId)
            throws FooException {
        return fooService.findFoo(fooId));
    }
}

public interface FooService{

    FooResponse findFoo(String fooId);

}

@Service
public class ProspectAssetServiceImpl implements ProspectAssetService {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Override
    public FooResponse findFoo(String fooId){
        FooEntity fooEntity = fooRepository.findByFooId(fooId));
        return convertBomToMessaging(fooEntity);
    }


}

public class Foo {

    private String fooId;

    private String fooName;

    //getters and setters

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_table")
public class FooEntity {

    private String fooId;

    private String fooName;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Second Service:

```
@RestController
..
public class ZooController  {

    @Autowired
    private ZooService ZooService;

    @GetMapping
    public ZooResponse findZoo(
            @PathVariable(Zoo_CONSTANT.PATH_VARIABLE_Zoo_ID) String ZooId)
            throws ZooException {
        return ZooService.findZoo(ZooId));
    }
}

public interface ZooService{

    ZooResponse findZoo(String ZooId);

}

@Service
public class ProspectAssetServiceImpl implements ProspectAssetService {

    @Autowired
    private ZooRepository ZooRepository;

    @Override
    public ZooResponse findZoo(String ZooId){
        ZooEntity ZooEntity = ZooRepository.findByZooId(ZooId));
        return convertBomToMessaging(ZooEntity);
    }


}

public class Zoo {

    private String ZooId;

    private String ZooName;

    //getters and setters

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Zoo_table")
public class ZooEntity {

    private String ZooId;

    private String ZooName;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Suggest me an efficient way to combine these two together?

Comment: It looks like you have different entities with different properties in your example. It seems to contradict the explanation. Could you clarify please?

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt - I have a scenario where i need to persist something into two entitites. For example, Foo is a potential customer, which i need to store as an entity, where as Zoo is considered as a customer.  These two are having the same properties, but i need to persist them in different entities. I am following a file structure like i mentioned earlier. I am looking for an efficient way of doing this. Hope i was able to give enough clarity.